# extremely frustrating with eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse

I have a simple html file "index.html" in my java EE project. I changed the contents of the file, changed some links. But when I run it from eclipse nothing's changing. When I run it outside of eclipse it opened with the updated contents. Finally I became frustrated I uninstalled and reinstalled eclipse and tomcat. I imported my previous project and nothing changed in the html file! I deleted all content and run it and even though the page is empty it still shows the old page! What is going on? How can I fix this?

Comment: Whenever you make a change in a file follow these steps: stop the server->right click on server-> add/remove -> remove the project->add again->start the server again->run the page->click refresh or simply enable "Publish changes immediately when server is started"  if the contents are not changing you should always refresh, the cached page may be the one being displayed.

Comment: @Nivedita "always refresh, the cached page may be the one being displayed." - yes I think that's the reason. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: posted the same as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you make a change in a
file follow these steps:

- stop the
  server
- right click on server
- add/remove
- remove the project
- add
  again
- start the server again
- run the page
- click refresh or simply
  enable **Publish changes
  immediately when server is started**

If the contents are not changing you
should always refresh the whole page.
Sometimes the cached
page may be the one being
displayed.

Hope this helps :)